# Android Java:Getting your longitude and latitude on button click

Tags: java, android

This is my first time asking,so hi everybody:

I can get my location with the listener,but i want to get it when a button is clicked.

thanks in advance everyone.

comment if you want to ask me anything.

Here is the main activity:

```
package com.Lottery;

import com.example.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView tv;
    Button b;
    LocationManager mlocManager;
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    }


    /* Class My Location Listener */

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
        @Override

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){

            String Text = "location: " +
                    "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
                    "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

            tv.setText(Text);

        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

            //nothin
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){

            //nothin
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            //nothin
        }
    }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    //i wanto do it here

    }
}/* End of UseGps Activity */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do it the same way like in your `MyLocationListener` you can do it like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Location lastLocation = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    String locationInfo = "Location: " +
        "\nlatitude = " + lastLocation.getLatitude() +
        "\nlongitude = " + lastLocation.getLongitude();

    tv.setText(locationInfo);
}
```

Note that this doesn't actually request a new location update but rather returns the last one received (so it may be outdated). If your app requests location update continuously (via the specified provider - in your case `NETWORK_PROVIDER`) this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also note: not only may it be outdated, it may not even exist at all, which would throw a nice little NPE when you try to access the coordinates. You're better off saving the location every time it's updated on the device (using onLocationChanged, like @Ascorbin mentioned below) and then getting that saved location in your onClick method (like lavsprat suggests here). A combination of those two would make tremendous improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Save the `Location` as a class member of your `Main` class, you can then access it from anywhere in the class. 
Keep in mind that it might be null when the button is clicked if the button is clicked before `onLocationChanged` was called.

```
package com.Lottery;

import com.example.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView tv;
    Button b;
    LocationManager mlocManager;

    Location location = null; 

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    }


    /* Class My Location Listener */

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
        @Override

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){

           location = loc; 



        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

            //nothin
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){

            //nothin
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            //nothin
        }
    }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


                 String Text = "location: " +
                    "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +
                    "Longitude = " + location.getLongitude();

            tv.setText(Text);

    }
}
```

Comment: i want to get it when a button is clicked, not changed.

Comment: See lavspat's answer if you need to get the location immediately, you are not guaranteed that the device has a last known location though.